# Why twig code in craftcms can't generate new code on localhost?

Tags: twig, craftcms

In craftCMS I've created a field to load content but this field is not showing up when i change my code in the template. I've checked if I used the correct folder

At first i thought it was the cache but when i go to utilities to clear the cache the same error still occurs. Also when I write any new character other than twig code the browser gives an error with the new code but when I delete it, it's still the same old code

1. Here is my code:

```
{% extends "index" %} 
{% block content %}
    This is not generate on my local
    <div class="can't load new code below and new class right here"
        {{ entry.headingDescription }}
        {{ entry.headingTitle }}
    </div
{% endblock %}
```

2. My structure:

[image: 1]

Comment: Do note you have to include the extension when extending, including and embedding templates. The correct code should be `{% extends "index.twig" %}`, please adjust and check if this solves your issue

Comment: Can you please post the error message as well and have you tried renaming the fields in that case are you able to get the data? and are you are putting the code on index. twig file?
As I can see the folder and file are correct post the error as well so we can help you better.